Gazebo crashes immediately - Segmentation fault (Address not mapped to object [0x220])
I installed ROS2 Jazzy successfully on a laptop running Ubuntu Noble 24.04 with an Intel Xe graphics card, and installed Gazebo Harmonic using:
sudo apt-get install ros-jazzy-ros-gz

Then running gz-sim produces the quick start window. From there, if I choose and run any of the pre-installed .sdf files, the program crashes and produces this output:
[GUI] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1285]  Unable to create the rendering window: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): currentGLContext was specified with no current GL context in GLXWindow::create at ./.obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/gz_ogre_next_vendor-prefix/src/gz_ogre_next_vendor/RenderSystems/GL3Plus/src/windowing/GLX/OgreGLXWindow.cpp (line 165)
[GUI] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1285]  Unable to create the rendering window: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): currentGLContext was specified with no current GL context in GLXWindow::create at ./.obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/gz_ogre_next_vendor-prefix/src/gz_ogre_next_vendor/RenderSystems/GL3Plus/src/windowing/GLX/OgreGLXWindow.cpp (line 165)
[GUI] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1285]  Unable to create the rendering window: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): currentGLContext was specified with no current GL context in GLXWindow::create at ./.obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/gz_ogre_next_vendor-prefix/src/gz_ogre_next_vendor/RenderSystems/GL3Plus/src/windowing/GLX/OgreGLXWindow.cpp (line 165)
[GUI] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1285]  Unable to create the rendering window: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): currentGLContext was specified with no current GL context in GLXWindow::create at ./.obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/gz_ogre_next_vendor-prefix/src/gz_ogre_next_vendor/RenderSystems/GL3Plus/src/windowing/GLX/OgreGLXWindow.cpp (line 165)
[GUI] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1285]  Unable to create the rendering window: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): currentGLContext was specified with no current GL context in GLXWindow::create at ./.obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/gz_ogre_next_vendor-prefix/src/gz_ogre_next_vendor/RenderSystems/GL3Plus/src/windowing/GLX/OgreGLXWindow.cpp (line 165)
[GUI] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1285]  Unable to create the rendering window: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): currentGLContext was specified with no current GL context in GLXWindow::create at ./.obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/gz_ogre_next_vendor-prefix/src/gz_ogre_next_vendor/RenderSystems/GL3Plus/src/windowing/GLX/OgreGLXWindow.cpp (line 165)
[GUI] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1285]  Unable to create the rendering window: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): currentGLContext was specified with no current GL context in GLXWindow::create at ./.obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/gz_ogre_next_vendor-prefix/src/gz_ogre_next_vendor/RenderSystems/GL3Plus/src/windowing/GLX/OgreGLXWindow.cpp (line 165)
[GUI] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1285]  Unable to create the rendering window: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): currentGLContext was specified with no current GL context in GLXWindow::create at ./.obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/gz_ogre_next_vendor-prefix/src/gz_ogre_next_vendor/RenderSystems/GL3Plus/src/windowing/GLX/OgreGLXWindow.cpp (line 165)
[GUI] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1285]  Unable to create the rendering window: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): currentGLContext was specified with no current GL context in GLXWindow::create at ./.obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/gz_ogre_next_vendor-prefix/src/gz_ogre_next_vendor/RenderSystems/GL3Plus/src/windowing/GLX/OgreGLXWindow.cpp (line 165)
[GUI] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1285]  Unable to create the rendering window: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): currentGLContext was specified with no current GL context in GLXWindow::create at ./.obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/gz_ogre_next_vendor-prefix/src/gz_ogre_next_vendor/RenderSystems/GL3Plus/src/windowing/GLX/OgreGLXWindow.cpp (line 165)
[GUI] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1293] Unable to create the rendering window after [11] attempts.
[GUI] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1191] Failed to create dummy render window.
[GUI] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1192] Please see the troubleshooting page for possible fixes: https://gazebosim.org/docs/fortress/troubleshooting
Stack trace (most recent call last):
#31   Object "/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_sim_vendor/lib/libgz-sim8-gui.so.8", at 0x75df23275360, in gz::sim::v8::gui::runGui(int&, char**, char const*, char const*, int, char const*, char const*)
#30   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5", at 0x75df222df3e7, in QCoreApplication::exec()
#29   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5", at 0x75df222d6a7a, in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>)
#28   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5", at 0x75df22335278, in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>)
#27   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0", at 0x75df21113a52, in g_main_context_iteration
#26   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0", at 0x75df21173716, in 
#25   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0", at 0x75df211145b4, in 
#24   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5", at 0x75df22335c0e, in 
#23   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5", at 0x75df222db94a, in QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendPostedEvents(QObject*, int, QThreadData*)
#22   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5", at 0x75df222d8117, in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*)
#21   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5", at 0x75df2196bd44, in QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*)
#20   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5", at 0x75df22306342, in QObject::event(QEvent*)
#19   Object "/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_gui_vendor/lib/gz-gui-8/plugins/libMinimalScene.so", at 0x75df016582d4, in gz::gui::plugins::RenderWindowItem::Ready()
#18   Object "/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_gui_vendor/lib/gz-gui-8/plugins/libMinimalScene.so", at 0x75df01657f64, in gz::gui::plugins::RenderThread::Initialize[abi:cxx11]()
#17   Object "/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_gui_vendor/lib/gz-gui-8/plugins/libMinimalScene.so", at 0x75df0166835f, in gz::gui::plugins::RenderThreadRhiOpenGL::Initialize[abi:cxx11]()
#16   Object "/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_gui_vendor/lib/gz-gui-8/plugins/libMinimalScene.so", at 0x75df0165cb69, in gz::gui::plugins::GzRenderer::Initialize[abi:cxx11](gz::gui::plugins::RenderThreadRhi&)
#15   Object "/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_rendering_vendor/lib/libgz-rendering8.so.8", at 0x75df004fc162, in gz::rendering::v8::RenderEngineManager::Engine(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
#14   Object "/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_rendering_vendor/lib/libgz-rendering8.so.8", at 0x75df004fbeb4, in gz::rendering::v8::RenderEngineManagerPrivate::Engine(EngineInfo, std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
#13   Object "/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_rendering_vendor/lib/libgz-rendering8.so.8", at 0x75df00504a1f, in gz::rendering::v8::BaseRenderEngine::Init()
#12   Object "/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_rendering_vendor/lib/gz-rendering-8/engine-plugins/libgz-rendering-ogre2.so", at 0x75dea7dfe416, in gz::rendering::v8::Ogre2RenderEngine::InitImpl()
#11   Object "/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_rendering_vendor/lib/gz-rendering-8/engine-plugins/libgz-rendering-ogre2.so", at 0x75dea7e011fb, in gz::rendering::v8::Ogre2RenderEngine::InitAttempt()
#10   Object "/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_ogre_next_vendor/lib/libOgreNextMain.so.2.3.3", at 0x75dea7932bef, in Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::initialiseAllResourceGroups(bool)
#9    Object "/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_ogre_next_vendor/lib/libOgreNextMain.so.2.3.3", at 0x75dea7932273, in Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::parseResourceGroupScripts(Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::ResourceGroup*)
#8    Object "/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_ogre_next_vendor/lib/libOgreNextMain.so.2.3.3", at 0x75dea7973f4c, in Ogre::ScriptCompilerManager::parseScript(Ogre::SharedPtr<Ogre::DataStream>&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
#7    Object "/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_ogre_next_vendor/lib/libOgreNextMain.so.2.3.3", at 0x75dea796c9d4, in Ogre::ScriptCompiler::compile(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
#6    Object "/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_ogre_next_vendor/lib/libOgreNextMain.so.2.3.3", at 0x75dea796c70b, in Ogre::ScriptCompiler::compile(Ogre::SharedPtr<std::__cxx11::list<Ogre::SharedPtr<Ogre::ConcreteNode>, Ogre::STLAllocator<Ogre::SharedPtr<Ogre::ConcreteNode>, Ogre::CategorisedAllocPolicy<(Ogre::MemoryCategory)0> > > > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
#5    Object "/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_ogre_next_vendor/lib/libOgreNextMain.so.2.3.3", at 0x75dea797e973, in Ogre::MaterialTranslator::translate(Ogre::ScriptCompiler*, Ogre::SharedPtr<Ogre::AbstractNode> const&)
#4    Object "/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_ogre_next_vendor/lib/libOgreNextMain.so.2.3.3", at 0x75dea797f852, in Ogre::TechniqueTranslator::translate(Ogre::ScriptCompiler*, Ogre::SharedPtr<Ogre::AbstractNode> const&)
#3    Object "/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_ogre_next_vendor/lib/libOgreNextMain.so.2.3.3", at 0x75dea7982166, in Ogre::PassTranslator::translate(Ogre::ScriptCompiler*, Ogre::SharedPtr<Ogre::AbstractNode> const&)
#2    Object "/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_ogre_next_vendor/lib/libOgreNextMain.so.2.3.3", at 0x75dea79f3756, in Ogre::Technique::createPass()
#1    Object "/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_ogre_next_vendor/lib/libOgreNextMain.so.2.3.3", at 0x75dea78ee07f, in Ogre::Pass::Pass(Ogre::Technique*, unsigned short)
#0    Object "/opt/ros/jazzy/opt/gz_ogre_next_vendor/lib/libOgreNextMain.so.2.3.3", at 0x75dea781dc66, in Ogre::Hlms::createDatablock(Ogre::IdString, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, Ogre::HlmsMacroblock const&, Ogre::HlmsBlendblock const&, std::vector<std::pair<Ogre::IdString, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, Ogre::STLAllocator<std::pair<Ogre::IdString, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, Ogre::CategorisedAllocPolicy<(Ogre::MemoryCategory)0> > > const&, bool, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
Segmentation fault (Address not mapped to object [0x220])

I tried doing the troubleshooting step in the Gazebo docs for Wayland systems like mine, and ran env -u WAYLAND_DISPLAY gz sim -v 4 shapes.sdf, but the same issue popped up again.

It works using QT_QPA_PLATFORM=xcb gz sim

Try
sudo gz sim -v 4 shapes.sdf


The solution provide by @PrattPrakash worked well for me. (I installed ROS 2 Jazzy Jalisco and gazebo Harmonic). I found that adding the following setup to my .bashrc1 file prevents the need to manually enter the QT_QPA_PLATFORM=xcb gz sim ... command every time:
echo 'export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=xcb' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc

Before making this change, it’s essential to verify that it'll not break something else you might need. However, based on my knowledge, it should work seamlessly for ROS 2 and Gazebo.
